# On giving the value of a x coordinate, y coordinate and radius of the circle,how to get a circular portion from an image in matlab?

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, signal-processing

On giving the above values how can we make modifications in that part alone.Can that part be used for image enhancements or watermarking?

```
value of x= some coordinate
value of y= some coordinate
radius of circle=r
```

Comment: it not very clear what you're asking. Read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) how to improve your question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to embed a watermark inside a circular region?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19809793/how-to-embed-a-watermark-inside-a-circular-region)

Answer (score 1):

A simple possibility, genuinely based on image-processing-like tools, is to threshold the [distance transform](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/images/ref/bwdist.html) around the center points.

In principle, this approach would allow you to consider even more than one center at a time.

E.g. for

```
 R = 20;
 Cx = 150;
 Cy = 150;
```

[image]

[image]

```
 %%% // parameters
 R = 20;
 Cx = 150;
 Cy = 150;

 %%% // Demo pict
 clear X map;
 figure   
 load('flujet','X','map');
 imagesc(X);
 colormap(map);

 %%% // mask of the centers
 mask = false(size(X));   
 mask(Cy,Cx)=true;

 %%% // distance transform
 D = bwdist(mask);

 %%% // thresholding with radius R
 X = X.*(D<R);
 figure
 imagesc(X);
 colormap(map);
```